# Como instanciar chave primaria em outra classe MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho a classe `Funcionario` e `Projeto`. As duas tem os respectivos Id's.

Quero criar uma classe `ProjetoFuncionario` e gostaria de instanciar a chave primária das duas nessa classe.

Como possa fazer?

```
namespace Exercicio1.Models
{
    public class Projeto
    {
        public long id_Projeto { get; set; }
        public string nome_Projeto { get; set; }

        public List<FuncionarioModel> listaProjeto = new List<FuncionarioModel>();
    }
}
```

E também a classe `Funcionario`:

```
public class FuncionarioModel
{
    string dataAtual = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();

    public long id_funcionario { get; set; }
    [Required]

    [DisplayName(" Nome.: ")]
    [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = " O Campo Nome permite apenas 40 caracteres!")]
    public string nom_funcionario { get; set; }
    [Required]
}
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer com instanciar as chaves primárias? Você quer fazer uma referência dessa nova classe para Funcionario e Projeto eu suponho... para isso basta criar uma classe assim: `public class ProjetoFuncionarioModel { public ProjetoModel Projeto { get; set; } public FuncionarioModel Funcionario { get; set; } }`.

Comment: eu quero criar uma clase PROJETOFUNCIONARIO nessa classe eu quero instanciar a chave de funcionario e a chave de projeto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Quero criar uma classe ProjetoFuncionario...

Não existe a necessidade de se criar uma classe como **ProjetoFuncionario** para expressar esses relacionamentos. Isso normalmente ocorre ao criar as tabelas do banco de dados, aí sim você cria uma tabela para expressar o relacionamento, mas a modelagem de seus objetos não ficará exatamente como você modela seu banco de dados.

Você pode trabalhar apenas as classes `Funcionario` (ou `FuncionarioModel` como você chamou) e Projeto mesmo.

> ...gostaria de instanciar a chave primaria das duas nessa classe. Como possa fazer?

Na verdade você não instancia chave primária, pois chave primária está relacionada a campo(s) do objeto(s). Como sabemos, você cria instâncias de objetos (como **Funcionario**, **Projeto**, etc...).

Você pode criar a instância da classe `Projeto`, criar a(s) instância(s) do(s) Funcionário(s) do projeto e adicionar cada objeto `Funcionario` na lista. Quando você salvar o Projeto no banco de dados, o framework que você usar (Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc...) fará a associação (salvando as informações nas tabelas de `Projeto`, `Funcionario` e `ProjetoFuncionario` e até mesmo gerando os Ids automaticamente) para você.

```
//Instancia os objetos para exemplificar
Projeto projeto_novo = new Projeto() { nome_Projeto = "Projeto 1", lista_funcionarios = new List<Funcionario>() };
Funcionario funcionario_novo1 = new Funcionario() { nom_funcionario = "Funcionário 1" };
Funcionario funcionario_novo2 = new Funcionario() { nom_funcionario = "Funcionário 2" };

//Adiciona os funcionários na lista
projeto_novo.lista_Funcionarios.Add(funcionario_novo1);
projeto_novo.lista_Funcionarios.Add(funcionario_novo2);
```

Um ponto de atenção que notei aqui é sobre os nomes de propriedades, pois, onde você está usando "listaProjeto" eu usei "lista_Funcionarios" no exemplo, apenas porque acredito que fica mais claro (apenas sugestão).

Se ainda não respondi sua dúvida, insira um comentário para que eu possa ajudar :-)

Comment: Entendi o que vc quis dizer, teoricamente era isso mesmo que eu precisava. Obrigada Renan!

Answer (score 1):

Apenas complementando a resposta do @Renan, na sua modelagem um `Funcionario` pode pertencer a apenas um `Projeto` e um `Projeto` tem vários `Funcionario`s. Numa outra interpretação da sua pergunta, você poderia querer que um `Funcionario` tenha vários `Projeto`s, e que um `Projeto` pode ter vários `Funcionario`s (cardinalidade N para N). Neste caso, é pertinente uma entidade `ProjetoFuncionario` da seguinte forma:

```
public class ProjetoFuncionario
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjetoFuncionarioId { get; set; }
    public int ProjetoId { get; set; }
    public int FuncionarioId { get; set; }

    public virtual Projeto Projeto { get; set; }
    public virtual Funcionario Funcionario { get; set; }
}
```

Aproveito para discutir a maneira que você usou para implementar, bem como sugerir algumas normativas para deixar seu projeto mais organizado:

```
namespace Exercicio1.Models
{
    [DisplayColumn("Nome")] // Esse atributo faz algumas configurações automáticas, como DropDowns, por exemplo.
    public class Projeto
    {
        [Key] // É boa prática anotar qual propriedade é chave primária.
        public long ProjetoId { get; set; } // O padrão do Entity Framework é ProjetoId ou apenas Id
        [Required] // Procure anotar campos não nulos como [Required], obrigatórios.
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        // Procure não instanciar propriedades de navegação; O Entity Framework faz isso pra você;
        // Não precisa limitar a coleção em List<>; Use ICollection<>, que permite mais recursos;
        // Procure anotar a propriedade de navegação com virtual para permitir herança.
        public virtual ICollection<ProjetoFuncionario> ProjetoFuncionarios { get; set; }
    }

    [DisplayColumn("Nome")]
    public class Funcionario
    {
        // Essa propriedade não tem necessidade de ficar aqui, então comentei.
        // public string dataAtual = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();

        [Key]
        public long FuncionarioId { get; set; } // Novamente coloquei essa chave na convenção.
        [Required] // Atributos são sempre em cima da propriedade alvo, não embaixo como estava.
        [DisplayName(" Nome.: ")]
        [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "O Campo Nome permite apenas 40 caracteres!")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProjetoFuncionario> ProjetoFuncionarios { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cigano, mesmo se tratando de uma cardinalidade N-N, não a necessidade de uma Entitidade para representar uma tabela de Link, neste caso Projeto pode ter uma ICollection<Funcionario> e Funcionario  ICollection<Projeto>.

Comment: @TobyMosque E se você precisar expressar campos adicionais dentro da associação, como isso poderia ser feito? E se você não quiser usar *Fluent API* no projeto por uma questão de normatização, como isso seria feito?

Comment: Normalmente eu adoto a mesma estratégia utilizada no modelo Database First, quando a tabela de relacionamento não tem outra finalidade que ligar as duas tabelas não existe a necessidade de criar uma entidade nova.

Comment: @TobyMosque Mas aí é que está: 90% dos sites que eu vejo por aí respondem isso. A ideia de dar uma resposta diferente que contempla todos os casos, a meu ver, é mais interessante.